# React JS set overflow scroll positions from parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, scroll

I need to store the scroll positions of components (Element) in a state object at the root level of my app (MyApp).

In order to render the scroll position of each Element, (as DOM style don't include a scrollTop property) I tried to pass the props to the scrollTop value of a ref object pointing to the JSX div, from a useEffect, but it fires an infinite loop. Any idea on what is going wrong here, better logic to propose ?

React code:

```
function MyApp() {
    const [scrolls, setScrolls] = useState([
        {element:"lorem", scrollTop:0},
        {element:"ipsum", scrollTop:0}
    ])
    function scrollElement(element, event) {
        const newScrolls = scrolls.map(e=>{return {...e}})
        newScrolls.map(e=>{
            if (e.element==element) {
                e.scrollTop = Math.round(event.target.scrollTop)
            }
        })
        setScrolls(newScrolls)
    }
    function Element(props) {
        const elementRef = useRef(null)
        useEffect(()=>{
            elementRef.current.scrollTop = props.scrollTop
        },[])
        return (
            <div >
                <div>{props.element+":"+props.scrollTop}</div>
                <div 
                ref={elementRef} 
                style={{height:"200px",   width:"200px", overflow: "scroll", border:"1px solid black"}} 
                onScroll={()=> props.scrollElement(props.element, event)}
                >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porttitor vulputate consequat. Suspendisse elementum massa at lectus venenatis, vel lacinia risus consectetur. Morbi eget vestibulum ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras et placerat leo, sit amet rhoncus tellus. Donec eget felis sed velit mollis mattis in id sem.</div>
            </div>    
        )
    }
    return (
        <>
            {scrolls.map(e=><Element
                key={e.element}
                element={e.element}
                scrollTop={e.scrollTop}
                scrollElement={scrollElement} />)}
        </>
    )
}
```